# Disable embedded html

Tags: javascript, html, capture

I want to embed another page inside a table on my page.  There are (at least) three ways to do this:

```
<table><tbody><tr>
  <td><object id="A" type="text/html" data="othersite.html"></object></td>
  <td><embed id="B" src="othersite.html"></td>
  <td><iframe id="C" src="othersite.html></iframe></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

However, I do not want these embedded pages to respond to mouse click events.

I know security prevents me from capturing events:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("Click captured and discarded"); }, true); // this is forbidden
```

But I would expect to be able to do something like

```
document.getElementById("A").disabled = true; // this should work but doesn't
```

Is there another way to make the embedded html ignore click events?

Thanks.

P.S. Sorry I can't give you an example, but jsfiddle appears to prevent embedded html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place a transparent `div` on top of an `iframe`:

```css
iframe, div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="C" src="http://wikipedia.com"></iframe>
<div></div>
```